# Bootstrap navbar collapse button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm currently making a website that utilizes the Bootstrap Navbar.  Everything seems to be working fine when making the window smaller, the triple bars show.  When I try to click on it though, it seems it doesn't want to drop down like it should.

I've included this in my code:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Here's what I used for the Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zachary Vincze</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If anyone could help, that'd be awesome.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You should add `jquery` before `bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your console/debugger window in your browser you'll see the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

You need to include jQuery *before* bootstrap for this functionality to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JQuery must be included first, if this doesn't fix you issue let me know and I will adjust my answer :)